# JFreeChart separate renderer for each series

Tags: java, jfreechart

Is it possible in **JFreeChart** to define separate renderer for each series? I see it is possible for datasets (renderer per dataset), but I wouldn't like to create a separate dataset for each series, should I?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to set a renderer per series, however the renderer itself can be configured per series. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need different renderers for different series and have the possiblity to change the renderer for the series on runtime. But I think I can do it this way that for each I will create separate dataset. I tried and it seems that memory usage isn't much bigger. Btw maybe you know why there is those distinction between dataset and series? When we should use datasets, when series?

Comment: My understanding is that datasets are for similar types of data, eg. if you're charting temp. and air pressure for 3 cities, I would use two datasets with 3 series each.

Comment: I see. Sounds reasonable and probably it is how it was intended for use. However when things get complicated it can be a bit tricky. For instance in your example if you would like to render temperatures differently (Paris=LineChart, NewYork=Area, Berlin=LineChart). But thanks for your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, by design JFreeChart maps each dataset to a renderer.  So if you want to have different renderers for some data series, you need to put each series into a separate dataset.

Mapping individual series to renderers would make equally good sense, but it wasn't implemented this way.